# How to generate array like 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 .... in python using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Of course,the array above is simple.We can use nested loop in python to generate it.

```
for i in range(1,10):
    for j in range(1,j+1):
        print(j)
```

But how can I use numpy in python to crate it quickly?

Comment: This is not something you're going to do over and over, so there's little point in optimizing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One quick way to generate the array is to use `np.tril_indices`. The column indices of the lower triangle of 2D square array is what you need:

```
np.tril_indices(10)[1] + 1

array([ 1,  1,  2,  1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3,  4,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  1,  2,
        3,  4,  5,  6,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,
        7,  8,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,
        7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Comment: Ah interesting "Return the indices for the lower-triangle of an (n, m) array". I was wondering what usefulness this would have!